# Set auto_increment for a primary key already created

Tags: mariadb, foreign-keys, primary-key, auto-increment, alter-table

I created two tables in a database on MariaDB: CasaProduzione and Produzione.

```
create table CasaProduzione(nome varchar(80) primary key);
alter table CasaProduzione add column id tinyint;
alter table CasaProduzione drop primary key;
alter table CasaProduzione modify nome varchar(80) not null;
alter table CasaProduzione modify id tinyint primary key auto_increment;

create table Produzione(
    id_film smallint not null,
    id_casaProduzione tinyint not null,
    data date not null,
        constraint `fk_produzione`
            foreign key (id_film) references Film(id),
            foreign key (id_casaProduzione) references CasaProduzione(id)
            on update cascade
            on delete restrict);

alter table Produzione modify data in smallint(4);
```

After i moved the column id in the table of CasaProduzione at first

```
alter table CasaProduzione modify column id tinyint(4) first;
```

Then i tried to set auto_increment in prevoius column

```
alter table Produzione modify column id tinyint(4) auto_increment;
ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'Produzione_ibfk_1' of table 'Film.Produzione'
```

So i tried to cancel the foreign key from Produzione

```
alter table Produzione drop foreign key fk_produzione;
```

but the result is the same.
What am I doing wrong?

After suggestion from the comment, I post here the result of this command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Film.Produzione \G;  
*************************** 
1. row 
***************************        
Table: Produzione 
Create Table: 
CREATE TABLE Produzione ( 
    id_film SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL, 
    id_casaProduzione TINYINT(4) NOT NULL, 
    DATA SMALLINT(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY fk_produzione (id_film), 
    KEY id_casaProduzione (id_casaProduzione), 
    CONSTRAINT Produzione_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_casaProduzione) REFERENCES CasaProduzione (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ) 
ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 

1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: There are a few things missing; like where in your `CREATE TABLE Produzione` statement does the column `id` and the foreign key creation of `Produzione_ibfk_1` exists?

Comment: @FanoFN: Yeah, because at the begin i believed that `nome` can be a primary key. So, after, I deleted the primary key on `nome` (row 3) for create `id` and set on it the primary key and auto_increment (row 5).
I do not remember to have created a constraint called `Produzione_ibfk_1` although the system tells that it exist. In any case i do not know how check

Comment: Can you post the result of this query `SHOW CREATE TABLE Film.Produzione;`?

Comment: @FanoFN: I do not understand how the constraing `Produzione_ibfk_1` was created. In any case i deleted it
`alter table Produzione drop foreign key Produzione_ibfk_1;`

Comment: Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. Please format code & output reasonably. See the edit help re code blocks. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please use standard punctuation & spelling (& spell check). PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by @FanoFN, with the command

```
show CREATE TABLE Film.Produzione \G;
```

the system showed me the constraint on the table Produzione. The system created the constraint `Produzione_ibfk_1`
I deleted this constraint with the command

```
alter table Produzione drop foreign key Produzione_ibfk_1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.130 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

After I can applied the command

```
alter table Produzione modify column id tinyint(4) auto_increment;
```

Thanks a lot